# Help identifying a young adult book series from the 2000s (closer to 2010-2017) about vampires

Tags: story-identification, books, novel, vampire

I can't remember the title or characters so here we go.

Young adult book series (2000 closer to 2010-2017) with female protagonist in high school who turns into a vampire (missing several days of school). Her father comes to live with her because he is a vampire.

The female protagonist's love interest is a guy whose family aren't vampires but have enhanced abilities to keep vampires in check.  The two protagonists were friends when they were little but grew separate as they grew up. People try to keep the two separated but love prevails.

The male protagonist grounds himself using a tree. There is a scene that occurs during class where both protagonists share along with some other characters. Both protagonists can read each other's minds.

To test it out, male protagonist thinks about kissing another girl and female protagonist snaps her pen, proving they can read each other's minds.